# Adjust brush size scrubber in PS?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

Is there a way to modify how the brush size scrubber works?

Once you get into the larger brush sizes the scrubber makes huge exponential jumps in pixel size. Two thirds of the scrubber are taken up by sizes like 0-100px but beyond the exponential increases are too big to be workable. I have to manually type in the size I want which is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't change the default behaviour of the brush size scrubber.

What you can do is use your keyboard <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> keys to change the size in single increments and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> to change the size in increments of 10. Dragging the scrubber automatically selects the value so theres no need to select the input box again, just drag the scrubber then refine with your keyboard.

Once you get close to the max 300 size with the scrubber it should still be easy enough to get within 5-10 of where you want anyway, so dragging the slider relatively close to the value you want then using your keyboard to refine the value should be easy enough.

Without using the scrubber you can also <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Click/drag</kbd> (OS X) or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right click/drag</kbd> (Win) to change brush size, which *may* be easier, although I think the behaviour is the same. Left and right is for size, up and down is for hardness.

Comment: I usually just `[]` but otherwise the bottom part `Ctrl+Opt+Drag` is what I'd go for. On Wacom its easy to set that as a keypress too.

Comment: The thing with `[]` is that it increases in bigger increments once you get  closer to the max size (which isn't something I do much but thats what the question is asking for). As far as I can tell, using `up/down` is the only way to change in `1`s once you get to that size

Comment: ... I understand the question and agree with and upvoted your answer. Was just saying of the options I'd rather use Ctrl+Opt+Drag to fine tune the size at the upper limits before doing single pixel increments or guessing at size.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! I thought you were saying you rather click/drag instead of doing single increments... It's late here, I should sleep -_-

Comment: Great tips, thanks guys. Didn't know about the keyboard shortcuts.